# How to add extra data to GTK widgets?

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

In GTK+3 how should I add/attach extra data to a GTK widget (like `Control.Tag` in C#)? I want to do this in Python.

Something like this:

```
# To set
image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_extra({"src": "./images/bitmap.png"})

# To use
image_src = image.get_extra().get("src")
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with gtk, what's stopping you from doing like `button_instance.my_tag = 3`?

Comment: @TankorSmash Is that a good practice in Python?

Comment: I guess it all depends on what you're trying to do exactly. Maybe subclassing the widget would be better. Hard to say without knowing more. Could be worth asking another one like 'should I extend a gtk widget if I want to add custom data'.

Comment: You can absolutely just set normal Python attributes on the objects. It's not good Python practice to limit yourself to what must be done in C or C# :-)

Answer (score 2):

If that's some data you want to pair with a GObject (and GtkWidgets are GObjects), then [set_data](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.set_data) is the way to go.

**EDIT**: that's true for C, but not in python according to your testing.

Comment: It throws exception: **RuntimeError: Data access methods are unsupported. Use normal Python attributes instead**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's interesting because the documentation link I gave is the python one and there's no information about that. Maybe there's something about that in the python + GTK+ 3 tutorial ? https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html